# git move a branch's start forward in the tree

Tags: git, branch, rebase

Okay I almost have this rebase thing figured out.

I can feel a breakthrough coming - here is the tipping point:

How do I do a rebase to go from:

```
A - - B - - C - - D - - E (HEAD)
|
\ - - F - - G (branch1)
```

To:

```
A - - B - - C - - D - - E (HEAD)
                  |
                  \ - - F - - G (branch1)
```

I don't just want to merge HEAD~1 into branch1, I think I want to rebase branch1 right?

I feel like I almost grok this - help!?

Comment: Turns out this *is* the simplest use of rebase. I guess I wasn't getting it because I was making it too complicated!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is a standard `rebase`, there's nothing tricky going on. You want to:

```
git checkout branch1
git rebase D
```

Comment: @wil It's trickier if you want to rebase part of a branch, like if you wanted to have G branched off D but leave F branched off A. In this case you're just changing the base of branch1 to be D instead of A

Answer (score 3):

This can be done with git rebase:

```
git checkout branch1
git rebase {COMMIT ID of D}
```